# Set primary ethernet card on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I am pretty new to networking, and currently I'm running into issues with my setup. I have an ASUS PCI-E Wlan Card, which is connected to a network (I'll call it `A`), which is connected to the internet.

Furthermore I have a private network `B` without internet access connected to my motherboards ethernet port. I did not configure anything at all and it seems to work. I can reach with `192.168.1.XXX` every device in my local network `B` all the time and I have internet access on my computer via `A`. But when loading a website in firefox, it sometimes takes a couple of seconds. This is not the case when disconnecting from `B`.

I tried bridging the two networks under `Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections` , but this slows both connections down, so they become unuseable.

What I thought might be the issue is that the computer always tries to reach the internet first via `B` and not instantly via `A` and this causes those delays (I sometimes wait about 5-10 seconds until the page loads).

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Route print output

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
  3...........................Nlwt Tun
 11...........................NordLynx Tunnel
 39...00 15 5d b2 ce 84 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
  7...00 ff 2e 79 1c 9f ......TAP-NordVPN Windows Adapter V9
 25...70 85 c2 b0 59 72 ......Intel(R) I211 Gigabit Network Connection
 16...ae 22 0b be 07 c1 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 20...ae 22 0b be 0f c1 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
 14...ac 22 0b be 07 c1 ......ASUS PCE-AC68 802.11ac Network Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.4     25
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.44.1   192.168.44.188     35
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link     169.254.57.70    261
    169.254.57.70  255.255.255.255         On-link     169.254.57.70    261
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     169.254.57.70    261
     172.27.240.0    255.255.240.0         On-link      172.27.240.1    271
     172.27.240.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.27.240.1    271
   172.27.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.27.240.1    271
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.1.4    281
      192.168.1.4  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.4    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.4    281
     192.168.44.0    255.255.252.0         On-link    192.168.44.188    291
   192.168.44.188  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.44.188    291
   192.168.47.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.44.188    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     169.254.57.70    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.4    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.44.188    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.27.240.1    271
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     169.254.57.70    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.4    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.44.188    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.27.240.1    271
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
 11    261 fe80::/64                On-link
 25    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 14    291 fe80::/64                On-link
 39    271 fe80::/64                On-link
 25    281 fe80::27:a6bf:168f:15c5/128
                                    On-link
 14    291 fe80::d3a:e0a9:ab43:865d/128
                                    On-link
 11    261 fe80::8df6:2969:45f4:3946/128
                                    On-link
 39    271 fe80::f4e2:7c78:67dc:1222/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 11    261 ff00::/8                 On-link
 25    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 14    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
 39    271 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: Add the output of `route print` to your post ([edit it](https://superuser.com/posts/1588916/edit)).

Comment: @harrymc done..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two default routes (`0.0.0.0`) on both interfaces, of which the one
via `192.168.1.4` has priority since its metric (25) is smaller
(and which I suppose is the one toward the internet).

This is the source of the confusion when you are trying to access a device
on the second adapter, as the first one would be consulted first.

You should remove the second default route and replace it by a route specific
to the network `192.168.44.x`. Set its priority higher with a metric such
as `1`, so it would be tried first for any access to an IP on that segment.
For IPs not in that segment, Windows will then not even try that second adapter.

The tool to use is the
[route command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/route_ws2008),
on which there exists extensive information on the internet.